# Azure API Management Instance Copy with Developer Portal Content

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I want to migrate all the content/data of 1 azure API management instance to a different instance.

While checking for options, came across backups, however the MSFT clearly informs that Developer Portal Content( i.e applications,products,subscriptions) are not included in the backup.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/28199

In this case, How can I migrate apim instance with also the contents of developer portal.

I have also looked at REST API's but there are no API's exposed for Applications in developer portal. Does that mean in case of disaster recovery , all the data of developer could very well be gone? Any better options here?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. We can take backup of applications, products and subscriptions of API management and restore it to another APIM. Only constraint is that both APIM should be of same tier.

Please follow following [blog] https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2015/04/29/azure-api-management-backing-up-and-restoring-configuration/

Other solution of instant DR is using 2 APIMs in different regions behind a traffic manager and maintain both APIMs.