# Azure API Management - Deploying Content and Stying across environments (staging, production, etc.)

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

As per the title, I'm looking for a way to promote content and changes across different instance of Azure API management developer portals, following normal best practices of moving from Dev, staging, Prod, etc.

Reading through previous posts and docs, there seemed to be some suggestions in relation to backup and restores, as per: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008071/azure-api-management-instance-copy-with-developer-portal-content](https://stackoverflow.com)

However, looking at the docs for APIM under the FAQ section, things seemed to have changed, with a pretty definitive NO being the answer to moving content via backup/restore [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-faq#is-the-portals-content-saved-with-the-backuprestore-functionality-in-api-management](https://stackoverflow.com)

Is anyone able to provide some guidance here on how to move content, or if it's even possible right now?

Comment: Deployment can be done by script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/automate-portal-deployments#automated-migration-script

Comment: Hi @MarkusMeyer, is this the only method available for deployment of content across environments? Reading into it, may be the solution I'm looking for, though seems like it may be prone to user error.

Comment: I think currently, there is no built-in functionality in Azure API Management to promote content and changes across different instances of the developer portal. The backup and restore functionality in API Management does not include the developer portal content, as you have mentioned.


One possible approach to move content between different instances of the developer portal is to use the Azure API Management REST API to export and import the portal content. You can use the REST API to export the portal content from one instance of API Management and then import it into another instance.